# Como reutilizar dados em uma classe sem precisar repetir estes dados?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

Como reutilizar `$dados`, `$key` e `$postFields` em todos os métodos sem precisar repetir todas as vezes estes dados dentro de cada método? Sim, estas variáveis terão sempre os mesmos valores.

```
class AllImoveis
{
    /**
     * Chaves de Autenticação
     * @var string
    */
    public function listar_imoveis()
    {
    $dados = array(fields =>array('tipo', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'codigo'));
    $key = '82CDA6l0BBepOykevP0472xl9ZoKuIlH';
    $postFields = json_encode($dados);  
    ...

    ...
    }
    public function listar_imovel()
    {
    $dados = array(fields =>array('tipo', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'codigo'));
    $key = '82CDA6l0BBepOykevP0472xl9ZoKuIlH';
    $postFields = json_encode($dados);  
    ...

    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Depende do que quer. Sem um contexto é difícil dizer. Talvez deva repetir mesmo. Talvez deveria criar um método que os retorne ou faça manipulações de forma mais granular, talvez tenha que transformá-los em campos da classe, talvez tenha que criar uma classe auxiliar, talvez seja melhor não fazer nada disto e procurar uma solução que você domine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para `$dados` e `$key` cire constantes já que o valor não vai mudar, `$postFields` se tornará um atributo da classe.

```
class AllImoveis {
  const KEY = '82CDA6l0BBepOykevP0472xl9ZoKuIlH';
  const DADOS = array(fields =>array('tipo', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'codigo'));
  private $postFields;
```

Comment: Mais uma dúvida pequena ... como insiro as ***const*** no método?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius você não pode fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

para que os valores sejam constantes declare como, const NOME_DA_CONSTANTE sem o sinal de cifrão.
para usar dentro dos métodos chame a variável deste modo self::NOME_DA_CONSTANTE
não é obrigatório mas é recomendado usar maiúsculas  para constantes.